# странное подключение к интернету на ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, dns, настройка

У меня есть модем, который раздает вай-фай, и есть ноутбук с убунтой 14.04.

Далее есть 3 ситуации:

1 - Я подключаюсь к интернету через вай-фай, у меня работает скайп, качаются торренты, могу гуглить, но кроме этого не могу перейти ни на один сайт, пишет ошибку DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG.

2 - отключаю вай-фай, подключаюсь к роутеру через провод, в итоге интернета нет вообще, ошибка ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED.

3 - подключаюсь к роутеру через вай-фай и всовываю шнур, в итоге интернет работает.

Я хочу, чтобы работал первый и второй способы тоже, подскажите, с чем проблемы, я подозреваю, что что-то с настройками dns на компе...

Стоит дополнить, что с телефона подключаюсь по вай-фаю и интернет на нем работает.

```
**Включен и вай-фай и шнур:**
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:d2:44:41:5d:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe41:5d80/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:8b:fd:7d:27:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e8b:fdff:fe7d:2774/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
~$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.4  metric 9 
~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.name

**только вай-фай:**
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:d2:44:41:5d:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe41:5d80/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:8b:fd:7d:27:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e8b:fdff:fe7d:2774/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
~$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.4  metric 9 
~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.name

**только шнур:**
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:d2:44:41:5d:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe41:5d80/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:8b:fd:7d:27:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
~$ ip r
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN


~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet manual
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
geteway ххххххххххх

nameserver ххххххххххх
nameserver ххххххххххх
```

Comment: а что у вас в `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: одно и то же все 3 раза, причем тоже, что и при выключенном интернете полностью. Я добавил в конец вопроса, что выводит консоль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить содержимое `/etc/network/interfaces` таким образом:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

После этого примените изменения:

```
service networking restart
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось...
я так перезагрузил интервейсы: ifdown eth0
ifup eth0

Comment: @fortunado, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: @fortunado, интерфейса `eth0` у вас нет. судя по конфигурации, только `eth1` (провод) и `wlan0` (wifi).

Comment: и что это значит?, я помню, что когда только купил комп, то он работал только по проводу или только по вай-фаю. Последний год пользовался им в режиме и то и то, а сейчас нужен только вай-фай, и проблема...
и да, я service networking restart делал

Comment: точнее так sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: В общем сеть у меня перезагружается так: sudo service network-manager restart . Я поковырялся, в итоге помогло, я просто в своих первоначальных интерфейсах исправил eth1 на eth0 и теперь всё работает) Большое спасибо, что направил куда нужно!)